# Java Folder Monitor for creation/deletion/etc?

Tags: java, file, directory

Is there a way to monitor folders in java to see when they are updated, ie file created, deleted, renamed,etc. And also is there any way to set it that it only looks for files that begin with a certain prefix, ie img?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java 7 there is a [`WatchService` API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) as part of NIO2. For earlier Java versions there's no pure Java solution except for manual polling.

Comment: I have recently reimplemented the code that I was working on when I asked this question originally. The WatchService from NIO2 is a very very tidy and easy to use method. Would highly recommend using it for anybody in the future reading reading this question.

Comment: Would you please provide me some good link, I am developing this using java 5...as you said it can be done by manual polling

Answer (score 4):

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256012/notify-a-button-if-the-number-of-files-in-a-directory-change/1256042#1256042) to a similar question.

The mechanisms detailed won't filter on a file name/type. You'll have to do that alongside the suggested solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inotify-java API that provides an event-based mechanism for monitoring Linux file system events using the inotify interface provided by glibc (versions 2.4 and up) and the Linux kernel, starting from 2.6.13. 
Features
Simple, easy to use feature-complete support for inotify
Low memory footprint API uses blocking calls yielding low CPU usage