# Java: Watching a Directory for Changes

Tags: java, linux, directory

I want to create a listener to detect directory change recursively (the main directory and its subdirectories). After a web search I found this [link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) that explains the use of the class WatchService from the Package java.nio.file that api exactly meets my needs but unfortunately it is only available in Java 7!
Then I return  to search again in order to find a [framework](http://jpathwatch.wordpress.com/) that allows the same and is compatible java 5 and java 6 but again there was a problem, because recursion is available for Windows and my application should use Linux!!
Can you offer me a solution: another framework, a way to do..

Comment: If the framework you linked works for one file , then making it work recusively for subfolders should not be a *major* problem , or is it ?

Comment: Why are people always scared to upgrade to the newest Java Version?

Comment: Because of the compiler optimisation bug released with Java 7? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894104/how-serious-is-the-java7-solr-lucene-bug

Comment: possible duplicate of [Notify a Button if the number of files in a directory change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256012/notify-a-button-if-the-number-of-files-in-a-directory-change)

Comment: @AdrianCox: that's not really a valid reason. JVM runtimes occasionally have bugs, even "stable" ones. And that particular one will soon be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I think you did a good discovery job and found a wonderful library jpathwatch. I do not understand what was your problem with recursion: I have not seen any restriction for linux in this library documentation.

But if for some reason jpathwatch cannot help you on linux, it is not a problem: you can run du command yourself. See this reference: http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_du.htm

If I were you I probably do the following: write simple script that runs du in loop. Then run this script from java from separate thread that is contiguously  reading the script's output and analyses it.

Comment: http://jpathwatch.wordpress.com/documentation/features/ that link explains that watching change in sub directories is only available for windows

Comment: Running `du` will cause a large amount of disk IO, and won't detect changes that don't modify file size.

Comment: That's right. If file size is not changed, du does not help. I just wanted to offer work-around.

Answer (score 1):

This is a kind of functionality that requires support of JVM or a native library, such as the one you've found for Windows. If you can't find anything **in Java** for Linux, I suggest asking for a binary Linux library (in a different question) and then build a Java native class on top of that.

I hope other people will help you better.

Answer (score 1):

To do this on Linux you need to use Java 7, or a native library that uses `inotify`. Have you considered the [JNotify library](http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/)? It looks like it handles recursion into subdirectories, including newly created ones.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

"The java.nio.file package provides a file change notification API, called the Watch Service API. This API enables you to register a directory (or directories) with the watch service. When registering, you tell the service which types of events you are interested in: file creation, file deletion, or file modification. When the service detects an event of interest, it is forwarded to the registered process. The registered process has a thread (or a pool of threads) dedicated to watching for any events it has registered for. When an event comes in, it is handled as needed."

Update: Ooops, just realized you already saw this.  I didn't realize this was only in Java 7 :-(

Comment: Ooops, just realized you already saw this. I didn't realize this was only in Java 7 :-(